# Does the sprint galaxy nexus support usb host mode?

Tags: android, galaxy

I was wondering if the sprint galaxy nexus supports the usb host mode?  As stated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html) it is supposed to be available on android versions above 3.1.  The galaxy nexus uses ice cream sandwich(version 4+) so it should have it.  [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oqq4L44jOM8) shows someone using the galaxy nexus with a usb mouse attached, so the stock galaxy nexus version should have this capability.  I was just wondering if Sprint changed the kernel in someway that disabled the usb host mode functionality.  [This site](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/compare/Samsung-Galaxy-S-III-Sprint,Samsung-GALAXY-Nexus-Sprint/phones/7099,7035) states that the galaxy s from sprint has "Mass storage device, USB Host, USB charging" as a feature but for the galaxy nexus from sprint the only feature listed is "USB charging."
I only realized this might be a missing feature because when I tried to set up a small test app using the Usb host mode api no device that I connected was ever recognized.  I tried pluggging the device in after device startup and before device startup.  I was reading the logcat wirelessly as is defined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html) so I could moniter what would happen when I was plugging a usb device in and removing it.  Logcat displayed nothing.  Any explanation or links to other sites saying that the Sprint galaxy nexus does or does not support usb host mode would be much appreciated(only Sprint, I beleive Verizon does support it, but I have a Sprint test device). Thanks.

Comment: Try the `dmesg` command in a terminal/shell window. On my phone many USB devices do not work because they need too much power. A self-powered USB hub (with attached wall wart) will help on my Android phone.

Comment: I found a line from the dmesg output (around line 275) that said: musb-hdrc: version 6.0, musb-dma, otg (peripheral+host).  So it looks like it should work since otg is what is used to drive a peripheral device.  For anyone else reading, the way I accessed the dmesg was: 1. adb [-d {device serial number}] shell 2. adb shell dmesg > newdmesgfile.txt

Comment: @TurboJ : please post this as an answer so I can accept it, thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Update: The Sprint Galaxy Nexus does support Usb host mode. Thank you to Turbo J for the "dmesg" guidance.  The problem was an incorrect USB OTG cable.  I bought one from a local store but it did not work.  This cable here is specialized to the Galaxy Nexus, I would buy something like this before starting a project: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0070HPQ28/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stock Galaxy Nexus works for me with USB Host mode. Been able to use the Ant+ receiver with no problems.